# what is this c++ gcc specific operator?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, operators

I have this code from an open source project, and was wondering what does this operator mean. 
what is this operator |= ?
used in the following code:

```
uint32_t a = VALUE1 | VALUE2; 
a |= VALUE1;
```

any idea ?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edc0fscw.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`|=` is not a GCC-specific operator - it is a standard C++ compound assignment operator. `a |= b` is roughly equivalent to `a = a | b`, where `|` is the bitwise-OR operator; except that `|=` has the precedence of `=` (very low precedence).